# Addition of extract at bottling time

Tags: bottling, fruit-extract

If I use 4oz of watermelon extract at bottling time,do I have to cut back on the amount priming sugar to prevent bottle bombs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would really depend on the contents of the extract. If the extract contains a significant amount of fermentable sugar, yes. If not, no.

Comment: These are the ingredients for the extracts I will use in a 5 gallon batch, should I still use the priming suger.

Comment: Hmm? I'm afraid I don't follow. What are the ingredients of the extract?

Comment: Husker Steve, maybe you should upvote an answer as well as accept it if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

The ingredients you posted on the other question

> Orange- oil of orange, alcohol, water. Watermelon-propylene glycol,
>   alcohol, water, natural watermelon flavor

don't contain any fermentables, so you should add priming sugar also.

Go easy on the amount - 4oz in 5 gallons is the upper limit what you need, so you could start with less than that, e.g 3oz.