# Additives for 5 gallon batch

Tags: beer

These are the ingredients for the extracts I will use in a 5 gallon batch, should I still use the priming suger. **Orange**- oil of orange, alcohol, water. **Watermelon**-propylene glycol, alcohol, water, natural watermelon flavor

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. If you intend this as a clarification on one of your several other questions about extracts, you should post it there.

Comment: So you want to know if the natural sugars in your additives will be enough to act as a primer when the brew is bottled/barrelled?

Comment: @MereDevelopment:  give it a go

Answer (score 2):

I [answered](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9453/addition-of-extract-at-bottling-time/9465#9465) this in your [previous](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9453/addition-of-extract-at-bottling-time) edition of this question. Yes, you do need to still add priming sugar because none of those additional ingredients are fermentable.

The priming sugar doesn't add any sweetness, if that's what your concern is, it just provides the sugars for the yeast to produce co2 to carbonate the beer. All of the sugar is converted.

With the extracts you are adding, you will get flat beer unless you also add priming sugar. So, yes, add priming sugar.